# How do I get past this place in the beginning of Owlbeak Castle?

Tags: giana-sisters-twisted-dreams

I'm stuck near the beginning of the Owlbeak Castle level in Giana Sisters:Twisted Dreams. I'm at the following place:

[image]

There are some supposedly helpful instructions on that sign, but I still can't get up that ledge and continue that level. How is this supposed to work, how do I get up there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You push the box a little bit to the left, and then it is easy to for "Punk Giana" to do a jump and then her dash-ability to reach the upper ledger.
[image]